# Using power and significance to calculate sample size in a one-tailed test?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, statistical-power, one-tailed-test

I am trying to determine the sample size needed to demonstrate that the lower boundary of a 95% CI is not lower than the population mean of another, with a power of .9. Right now the formula I'm using is:

$$n=((z_{\alpha} + z_{\beta})^2)*(\frac{\sigma}{\mu-\mu_0})^2$$

where $z_{\alpha}$ is the z-score for 95% CI (1.645 for one-sided) and $z_{\beta}$ is the z-score for 90% power (1.282). However, what I'm getting doesn't match up with what I see on a bunch of websites that offer free calculators, and those websites don't always match up with each other. Some of them with their formulas shown multiply the whole thing by 2. Others don't show their calculation. It seems like it should be a simple calculation, am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show two that give substantively different results? They're likely not doing the same thing (either a different test or defining some quantity differently from the ones in your calculation or doing a two tailed test without specifying that) -- e.g. one possible difference is sites that assume you're doing a paired test and give the total number of observations rather than the number of pairs. Usually these can be resolved by reading carefully what the site says but sometimes a little additional analysis is needed to make sure of what they're calculating.

Comment: Plesse explain "that the lower boundary of a 95% CI is not lower than the population mean of another, with a power of .9."  Elaborate the term power and pop mean of another